# Cannot share printer in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer

I'm using Windows 7 on my PC. I have turned on sharing for printer but I cannot find the share option when right clicking on my printer.

How can I share my printer on my PC? What's going on?

My network sharing configuration

[image]

Cannot see share option for the printer

[image]

My Windows 7 system

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this link [Share a printer @Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/share-a-printer), you should be able to find the printer sharing settings if you right click the printer and select `Printer Properties`. There should be a `Sharing` tab at the top of the properties window.

[image: Printer sharing tab]

Comment: It is `printer properties` not `properties`. It works for me now. Great thanks!